# Implementation of Singleton pattern with inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance, singleton

I have a `User` class. I want to create a `SingletonLoggedUser` class in order keep track of the data of the only logged in user in my application. How am I supposed to write this class following the **singleton pattern**?

Here's what I wrote at the moment:

```
public class SingletonLoggedUser extends User {
    private static SingletonLoggedUser instance = null;

    public synchronized static final SingletonLoggedUser getInstance() {
        if (SingletonLoggedUser.instance == null)
            SingletonLoggedUser.instance = new SingletonLoggedUser();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I suppose I should implement a `private` constructor as well. How?

Here's my `User` class implementation:

```
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Character type;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String surname, String userId, String password, String email, Character type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.type = type;
    }
// Getters and setters
}
```

Moreover since the first time I'm calling `getInstance()` I should get a new object **with all data relative to the logged in user**, I'm thinking about passing as argument the newly generated `User` object of the logged user... But all next times I'm calling `getInstance()` I want it to have just a `void` parameter. How can I do that?

Considered all the above questions... Am I maybe wrongly supposing I should use a **singleton** in this case?

Comment: what do you mean: a void parameter for getInstance() ?

Comment: @Stultuske I mean just `getInstance()` without parameters, as it is implemented right now

Comment: A singleton user doesn't really sound like a good idea. Unless you've just got one user, I mean; and then why isn't your `User` class a singleton too?

Comment: How you provide parameters in first-time logging. When creating a instance